# crawler4j asynchronously saving results to file

Tags: java, asynchronous, web-scraping, crawler4j

I'm evaluating crawler4j for ~1M crawls per day
My scenario is this: I'm fetching the URL and parsing its description, keywords and title, now I would like to save each URL and its words into a single file

I've seen how it's possible to [save crawled data to files](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/blob/master/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/imagecrawler/ImageCrawler.java). However, since I have many crawls to perform I want different threads performing the save file operation on the file system (in order to not block the fetcher thread). Is that possible to do with crawler4j? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using a `Queue` where you put the data to be written and which are then processed by one/more worker `Thread`s (this approach is nothing `crawler4j`-specific). Search for "producer consumer" to get some general ideas.

Comment: @qqilihq how do you share the queue with the crawler? I don't instantiate the crawler myself

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Code sample would help …

Comment: You create the crawler using this: `controller.start(MyCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);` which means the MyCrawler is getting instantiated by the controller, if I do this how can I share the queue? I can probably make it static (and therefore global) but that's usually a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) ([`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or similar) where you put the data to be written and which are then processed by one/more worker Threads (this approach is nothing crawler4j-specific). Search for "producer consumer" to get some general ideas.

Concerning your follow-up question on how to pass the `Queue` to the crawler instances, this should do the trick (this is only from looking at the [source](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/CrawlController.java) code, haven't used crawler4j on my own):

```
final BlockingQueue<Data> queue = …

// use a factory, instead of supplying the crawler type to pass the queue
controller.start(new WebCrawlerFactory<MyCrawler>() {
    @Override
    public MyCrawler newInstance() throws Exception {
        return new MyCrawler(queue);
    }
}, numberOfCrawlers);
```

Comment: I totally missed that factory. Thanks!